# Is there any difference between "crenellations" and "battlements"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Both these terms seem to refer to the jagged parapets you see on classic medieval castle towers.

Merriam-Webster [defines](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/battlement) "battlement" like this:

> a parapet with open spaces that surmounts a wall and is used for defense or decoration

And it [defines](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crenellation) "crenellation" like this:

> 1
>   :  battlement
>
> 2
>   :  any of the embrasures alternating with merlons in a battlement — see battlement illustration

Looking at the picture, it appears a "crenellation" is a gap in the parapet, and a "merlon" is a solid part, while "battlement" is the whole thing.  But this doesn't seem to match up with the usage in [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlement), which says "crenellation" is the *process* of converting a parapet into a battlement (by knocking holes in it).

If I specifically want to talk about what Merriam-Webster calls "merlons," what is the best word to use?

Comment: Why not use *merlons* if you "specifically want to talk about" them?

Comment: I'm concerned it may not be understood, or that Merriam-Webster's usage may not be universal.  OED says crenellations and battlements are synonyms.

Comment: If *merlons* be not understood, no single substitute word is likely to communicate the same specific meaning more clearly--you will simply have to explain. OED confirms meaning of *merlon.*

Comment: I seem to recall (from reading the history of Bodiam Castle in Sussex) that in the late medieval period one who wished to convert his home into a fortified castle had to be granted "license to crenellate."

Comment: M-W is incorrect in naming the gaps between the merlons as 'crenellations'. They are called 'crenels', and M-W (correctly) defines  the singular form, 'crenel', as 'one of the embrasures alternating with merlons in an embattlement'.